# Rotating picture while making it bigger

Tags: php

```
<?php

//11.811024   
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg('test.jpg');
$rotate = imagerotate($image, 90, 0);
list($width, $height) = getimagesize('test.jpg');

// Content type
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width * 11.811024, $height * 11.811024);

imagecopyresampled($image_p, $rotate, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width * 11.811024, $height * 11.811024, $width, $height);

imagejpeg($rotate);
```

It's not outputting any image, but when I comment out `imagecreatetruecolor` it does... Why? How can I fix this?

Comment: Where is your $height variable being set?

Comment: list($width, $height) = getimagesize('test.jpg');

Comment: Must have missed that line.

Comment: If you _temporarily_ remove your `header()` line, do you see any errors?

Comment: What are $width and $height if you output them before the imageCreateTrueColor line? (You'll have to comment out the content type line to make that work)

Comment: If I remove header, I am given Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 167384 bytes)

Comment: Width: 3543

Height: 2480

Comment: So, there's your answer, you don't have enough memory to create 2 images around that big. You could try to up your memory limit for that request, but anything using more then 128M memory would most likely have its result _stored_ somewhere to avoid repetitive use, and idealy done asynchronously outside the webserver.

Comment: Oh, make that 3 images, you could use a lot less memory if you `imagedestroy($image)` after you've created `$rotate`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be the reason:

```
bool imagecopyresampled ( resource $dst_image , resource $src_image , int $dst_x , int $dst_y , int $src_x , int $src_y , int $dst_w , int $dst_h , int $src_w , int $src_h )
```

Thats the function , the 1. Parameter is the destination in your case the emty picture $image_p

but you do `imagejpeg($rotate);`

take `imagejpeg($image_p);` to get the right output.

Also try to rotate it after you resampled it :)

Comment: Sorry, that's not the case, It imagejpeg tries to output the $image_p I just forgot to change it back mean while I was debugging.